# CROSS APPLY in NHibernate using criteria

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I want to select an employee with their pay information.

In the database the employee table has a one to many relationship with pay information, so I have to pick the employee with the highest sequence.

This SQL is working perfectly, but i want to do this in NHibernate:

```
 SELECT ID,
    EmployeeId,
    EmployeeCode,
    PayI.IsHourly,
    PayI.Sequence
    FROM Employee as E
    CROSS APPLY 
         (select  top 1 PayI.IsHourly,PayI.Sequence 
                 from PayInformation as PayI 
                 Where PayI.EmployeeId=E.EmployeeId 
                 order by PayI.Sequence desc 
          ) AS PayI

    Where E.EmployeeId=@EmployeeId
```

I know i can use criteria for that as I use it to filter records by EmployeeId but I do not know how to use Cross Apply in NHibernate.

```
NHibernate.ICriteria criteria = BmDaoSession.SessionFactory.OpenSession()
           .CreateCriteria(typeof(Employee));

criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("EmployeeId", employeeId));
return criteria.List<Employee>()[0];
```